# VLC can read mp3 but FFMPEG "could not find codec parameters"

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to process some audio with PyDub, but encountered an error, that seems to stem from ffmpeg, so I investigated, tried to process the audio file directly with ffmpeg and I reproduced the error:

```
PS C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\16311759704613> ffmpeg -i .\input.mp3 out.wav
ffmpeg version 2020-12-12-git-5148740e79-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      56. 62.100 / 56. 62.100
  libavcodec     58.115.102 / 58.115.102
  libavformat    58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.103 / 58. 11.103
  libavfilter     7. 93.100 /  7. 93.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[mpegts @ 00000220e533d3c0] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 00000220e533d3c0] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000220e533d3c0] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000220e533d3c0] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 00000220e533d3c0] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000220e533d3c0] changing packet size to 192
[mpegts @ 00000220e533d3c0] changing packet size to 188
[mpegts @ 00000220e533d3c0] changing packet size to 204
[mpegts @ 00000220e533d3c0] changing packet size to 192
.\input.mp3: could not find codec parameters
PS C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\16311759704613>
```

I tried to listen to the audio, VLC can open the file:

[image: VLC]

And Audacity can too:

[image: Audacity]

What can I do to process this file with ffmpeg?

Comment: Provide a link to `input.mp3`.

Comment: No thank you this is sentitive data. Plus providing a way to investigate would help future users solve a similar problem.

Comment: Without a sample input file I can only suggest trying a build of ffmpeg from the current git master branch.